# saving a group of files to a bigger file

Tags: java, file

Is it possible to save a group of files into a bigger, custom file? For my program, I looking for a means to package a number of files (lets say 15 sound files) as sub-files of one larger file. Reason being is that I want to protect the files that I have for my program to keep other users from directly having access and/or changing them. Something else similar to a zip or jar or just a custom version of the two.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use an encrypted zip file?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Hey! A local! I'm in O'side! :) I'm planning on doing my own encryption if I could store the files within one.

Comment: Don't do your own encryption - use Java's encryption libraries. No-one ever gets their own encryption right.

Comment: I strongly agree with @BarrySW19. Constructing a good encryption scheme is very, very difficult - more like a multi-year project for a team of mathematicians who have specialized in encryption than something that can be done well as part of a normal programming project.

Answer (score 2):

Output the files to a java.util.ZipOutputStream that is constructed using a javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream as its underlying stream. Use the corresponding input streams to read the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in one file after the other, encrypt it and write it out to your desired larger file. Then you just have to create a "Separation Marker" between each "file" so you know where a new file begins when you read the big file in again